# Brackets not displayed in MathML (firefox)

Tags: mathml

The MathML code is such:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mrow><mi>min</mi><mfenced open="(" close=")"><mrow><mn>9</mn><mo>,</mo><mn>6</mn></mrow></mfenced><mo>=</mo></mrow></math>
```

And it is displayed without brackets, sadly. (See https://prnt.sc/FBuGkh1NtM-7)

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `mfenced` seems to be deprecated and replaced by `mo`.
The `mrow` can be used for group subexpressions and provides hierarchy for an equation:

```
<mrow>
    <mi>f</mi>  
    <mo>(</mo>
    <mi>x</mi>
    <mo>)</mo>
 </mrow>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<math display="block">
  <mrow>
    <mo fence="true" form="prefix">(</mo>
    <mn>9</mn>
    <mo fence="true" form="postfix">)</mo>
  </mrow>
</math>
```

This works. No idea why the previous MathML didn't work, though.